# Firestore Firebase- Where can I find logs

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm experiencing too many reads from my Firestore database and I want to debug what's going on.
Based on other tickets and documentation I found out I can set Firestore log level
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#setloglevel

However, even If I set it to "debug" I'm not able to find the place where I can see those logs.
Are there somewhere in Firebase UI or do I have to subscribe to them somewhere in my application?

I really would like to avoid doing my own implementation of logging for Firestore by cloud functions.

I believe there has to be a way how to see logs at least for the last few minutes/hours.

Any ideas are welcome

Answer (score 1):

The logs enabled by `setLogLevel` are client-side logs, so they show in the debug output of your browser (or wherever you execute the code).

If you want to see server-side what calls were done to Firestore, have a look at the [usage dasboard](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/monitor-usage) in the Firebase or Cloud console, and [Cloud Logging for Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/monitor-usage#cloud-monitoring). Firestore recently also added support for [audit logging](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/audit-logging), which gives you more details on what exact account did each operation.

Finally, **read operations performed by the Firebase/Cloud console also count towards your quota**. So you might want to close the console and retry the operation to see if that makes a difference, as this is a common surprise for many developers when they're new to Firestore.